# Single IP address pointing to multiple different hosts?

Tags: firewall

We are having some touch panels put in that will control a new refrigeration system we are having put in.  These panels can be set up for remote access, so if an alarm goes off they can make any adjustments via the iOS app or through a web browser.

Is there a way I can use only one external IP, and then point them to the different hosts via what port it's coming in on or anything?  We have a Cisco ASA5510 as our firewall.  Or will I have to use a separate IP address for all 5 panels?  Thank you.

Comment: How is security on the panels handled? Can you configure the panels to accept requests on different ports? Can you configure port forwarding on the firewall? If so then probably yes.

Comment: He has an ASA55100, he will be able to do portforwarding. Matt, if you can make a quick drawing of the situation, it will be easier to formulate an answer.

Comment: To know if this is a feasible option, I would say the first think I would need answered is if you can specify the port in the app. If you can only specify the IP, then you will be limited to one panel in the app if you utilize different ports.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the touch panels can be forced to listen to their remote access on a different port than the default, you can set each one up on a separate port then create NAT rules in the ASA to map (example:)

external_ip:5555->panel_1_ip:5555

external_ip:5556->panel_2_ip:5556

etc

If they can't, you can set up NAT rules with different five different ports on the outside IP and map them to the different internal panel IPs like this:

external_ip:5555 -> panel_1_ip:3389

external_ip:5556 -> panel_2_ip:3389

external_ip:5557 -> panel_3_ip:3389

etc.